# trouble using regex to parse network output into groups

Tags: python-3.x, regex, networking

I am trying to use `re.sub` to parse out the output from `sh ip bgp neighbor <neighbor> advertised-routes`. This may or may not be the correct tool for the job but pyats does not parse the command correctly, and I am stuck.

rather than writing a parser, I was planning on collecting the raw output and then using regex to separate the output into fields that I can use to format the data.

so the part I am having an issue with is:

```
test_string = " *>   0.0.0.0          192.168.232.89                         0 209 65000 i"
new_string = re.sub('\*>\s+(\S+)\s+', '(\S+)\s{1,25}.\s{3,}', '\s+(.+?(?=[i\?]))', r'\1', test_string)

print(test_string)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mupch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 209, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Users\mupch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 303, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\mupch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\mupch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I tested the following regex on regex101.com to validate I am separating this out correctly:

```
\*>\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s{1,25}.\s{3,}[0-9]\s+(.+?(?=[i\?]))
```

this matches into the groups I want, the goal would be to only see the group `\1\2\3` and eliminate the garbage in between.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should pass the whole pattern `\*>\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s{1,25}.\s{3,}[0-9]\s+(.+?(?=[i?]))` and use `r'\1 \2 \3'` for the replacement to keep all 3 groups

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but you're calling `re.sub()` with 5 arguments that don't match the function signature. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Instead of a single `pattern`, you're passing in three separate patterns. So, it's trying to interpret the 4th argument (the string `r'\1'`) as a number, because that's what it's expecting (i.e. `count` with a default value of `0`). That's why you're receiving the `TypeError`.

---

Instead, pass the pattern as a single argument:

```
>>> test_string
' *>   0.0.0.0          192.168.232.89                         0 209 65000 i'

>>> regex
'\\*>\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s{1,25}.\\s{3,}[0-9]\\s+(.+?(?=[i\\?]))'

>>> re.sub(regex, r'\1, \2, \3', test_string)
' 0.0.0.0, 192.168.232.89, 209 65000 i'
```

---

Also, instead of using `re.sub()`, you can use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) which returns a [Match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), which gives you more flexibility to work with the results programmatically:

```
import re

TEST_STRING=r' *>   0.0.0.0          192.168.232.89                         0 209 65000 i'

REGEX=r'\*>\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s{1,25}.\s{3,}[0-9]\s+(.+?(?=[i\?]))'
result = re.search(REGEX, TEST_STRING)

print("Accessing matches by index...")
full_match = result[0]
group1 = result[1]
group2 = result[2]
group3 = result[3]

print(f'Full match: "{full_match}"\ngroup 1: "{group1}"\ngroup 2: "{group2}"\ngroup 3: "{group3}"')

print("\nGetting matches in a tuple...")
groups = result.groups()
for index, group in enumerate(groups, 1):
    print(f'group {index}: "{group}"')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 groups.py
Accessing matches by index...
Full match: "*>   0.0.0.0          192.168.232.89                         0 209 65000 "
group 1: "0.0.0.0"
group 2: "192.168.232.89"
group 3: "209 65000 "

Getting matches in a tuple...
group 1: "0.0.0.0"
group 2: "192.168.232.89"
group 3: "209 65000 "
```

---

When using `re.sub()`, if you want to discard the text that isn't contained within one of the groups, you have to specify a pattern that captures all of the text. Otherwise the text before and after the pattern is maintained.

Here's a script which demonstrates:

```
import re

TEST_STRING=r' *>   0.0.0.0          192.168.232.89                         0 209 65000 i'

REGEX=r'\*>\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s{1,25}.\s{3,}[0-9]\s+(.+?(?=[i\?]))'
sub_result = re.sub(REGEX, r'group 1: "\1", group 2: "\2", group 3: "\3"', TEST_STRING)
print(f'REGEX result:\n\'{sub_result}\'')

MATCH_ALL_REGEX=r'.*\*>\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s{1,25}.\s{3,}[0-9]\s+(.+?(?=[i\?])).*'
sub_result = re.sub(MATCH_ALL_REGEX, r'group 1: "\1", group 2: "\2", group 3: "\3"', TEST_STRING)
print(f'MATCH_ALL_REGEX result:\n\'{sub_result}\'')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 solution.py
REGEX result:
' group 1: "0.0.0.0", group 2: "192.168.232.89", group 3: "209 65000 "i'
MATCH_ALL_REGEX result:
'group 1: "0.0.0.0", group 2: "192.168.232.89", group 3: "209 65000 "'
```

Notice how the second result does not contain the leading space nor the trailing "i".

Comment: I am attempting to use regex groups, my understanding is that I can create a group, then call it by number ie:   re.sub('(a)b', r'\1d', 'abc').  I only want the information in the group and I want to rearrange it.  Everything outside the parenthesis is garbage data.

Comment: In my answer I demonstrated successfully using the pattern you specified, which contains multiple groups.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you meant. I added another example to demonstrate discarding leading and trailing text.

Comment: is there a way to call out the individual group that I want using the search method? Let's say that I just wanted to grab the route and path from the output (0.0.0.0 , 209 65000) or maybe I want to feed the groups into variables, how would i access those groups?

Comment: Expanded on using the `re.search()` function in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the request to match on the "route" and the "path" (or "weight_path" since I believe that leading zero is a "weight") AND at the same time assign these groups to variables.

We can leverage the [re.compile() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) along with "[named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)" to produce a groupdict that contains key-value pairs / variables.
The following demonstrates results using two different data strings to show the versatility of the pattern in conjunction with the named groups.

The default route provided in your example will be used as the simplest example -- no prefix length and no metric:

```
test_string = " *>   0.0.0.0          192.168.232.89                         0 209 65000 i"
```

A non-default route that includes a prefix length along with a metric is also used to provide a more real world example using the exact same pattern:

```
 tst_data = "*>i154.68.9.128/32     10.0.161.2                      100      0 64531 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 ?"
```

Here's the pattern (pat) with named groups, (?P<name>some-pattern), for

- "route"
- "next_hop"
- "metric"
- "weight_path"

followed by the resulting output:

```
>>> from re import compile
>>> 
>>> pat = compile(
...     r".+?(?P<route>"         # name for first named group
...      "(\d{1,3}\.){3}"        # 3 groups of 1 to 3 digits followed by a dot
...      "\d{1,3}(/\d{1,2})?)"   # 1 to 3 digits + optional slash + prefix length
...      "\s+(?P<next_hop>"      # name for second named group
...      "(\d{1,3}\.){3}"        # 3 groups of 1 to 3 digits followed by a dot
...      "\d{1,3})"              # 1 to 3 digits
...      "\s+(?P<metric>"        # name for third named group
...      "\d+(?=\s{2,}))?"       # 1 or more digits + at least 2 spaces; look ahead
...      "\s+(?P<weight_path>"   # name for fourth named group
...      "\d+(\s?\d+)+)"         # 1 or more digits + optional space + more digits
... )
>>> 
>>> test_string = " *>   0.0.0.0          192.168.232.89                         0 209 65000 i"
>>> data = pat.match(test_string)
>>> data['route']
'0.0.0.0'
>>> data['next_hop']
'192.168.232.89'
>>> data['metric']
>>> data['weight_path']
'0 209 65000'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> tst_data = "*>i154.68.9.128/32     10.0.6.2                      100      0 64531 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 ?"
>>> data = pat.match(tst_data)
>>> data['route']
'154.68.9.128/32'
>>> data['next_hop']
'10.0.161.2'
>>> data['metric']
'100'
>>> data['weight_path']
'0 64531 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539'
>>>
```

The "data" variable is an re.Match object, and the object contains a "groupdict" attribute, demonstrated above and detailed below.

```
>>> data.groupdict()  # when data = pat(test_string)
{'route': '0.0.0.0', 'next_hop': '192.168.232.89', 'metric': None, 'weight_path': '0 209 65000'}
>>> 


>>> data.groupdict()  # when data = pat(tst_data)
    {'route': '154.68.9.128/32', 'next_hop': '10.0.161.2', 'metric': '100', 'weight_path': '0 64531 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539'}
>>>
```

The named groups produce the dictionary of key-value pairs, the real "magic", and we're then able to arrange the data in any format needed.

```
>>> for key in data.groupdict():
...     print(f"key: {key:<11}  --  {data[key]}")
... 
key: route        --  154.68.9.128/32
key: next_hop     --  10.0.161.2
key: metric       --  100
key: weight_path  --  0 64531 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539 64539
>>>
```